# Insufficient Storage Space?

Tags: sd-card

I just bought an SD card with 8GB of memory (My old one had 2GB) and it's still saying I can't download or update any apps, and that there is insufficient storage space. I have an LGMS659 and I am very frustrated. Please help?

Comment: See the reason and possible solution in the questions tagged with [tag:insufficient-memory]. Also, give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage). You may have to delete an app or an app's data  to get some space for the said apps' installation.

Answer (score 0):

Loren, this is most likely due to your **internal storage** being full. By default, applications may be installing to your local storage. The easiest solution here will be to uninstall any unimportant applications and then install [AppMgrIII](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=en) or a similar application. This will then allow you to migrate larger applications to your SD card.

From memory (this may not be accurate) all applications that are not system installed applications can be moved to the SD card.

If you feel I have answered this please mark it so. If there is anything I have missed, or something wrong, let me know.